# Since upgrade to 5.34, Drupal accounts are not being created when a member signs up

Tags: drupal, civimember

This morning, I updated my dev sites from CiviCRM 5.25 to 5.34 and since then, I have found that Drupal accounts are not being created when a member signs up in CiviCRM.

We have a page for signing up for a membership, here - https://civi.artspan.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=3

On the live site, if someone fills out this form, a Drupal account is created for them and they are automatically logged in.  On the dev site, only a CiviCRM account is being created.

Nothing has changed between these two sites except for the CiviCRM update.

Under the profile settings for that form, "Drupal user account registration option? is marked as "account creation required".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We figured out a fix for this yesterday (it was reported yesterday as a wordpress issue)

There is a patch here
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19696

It will be part of 5.35.0 which will be released on Wednesday

If you are not comfortable patching and can't wait 2 days the other option is to upgrade to the rc version of 5.35.0

https://download.civicrm.org/latest/

(it won't change that much over the next 2 days but you can update the code base with the released version when it does drop)

Comment: Thank you!  We will probably just wait.